# zoom in images with css without resize

Tags: css, image, animation

I'd like to zoom in an image without resizing it. Does anybody know if this is possible? I already tried 'overflow: hidden' but it's not working unfortunately.

e.g. I have an image 300px x 300px i want the image to stay the same size (300x300) but enlarge the content.

Here is my code - thanks for any suggestions!

HTML

---

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="p1"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

---

```
div.wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.wrapper > div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transition: all 4s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 4s ease;
         -o-transition: all 4s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 4s ease;
            transition: all 4s ease;    

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
        -ms-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover; 
}

div.wrapper:hover > div{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
         -o-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2);          
}

#p1{
    background-image: url(../images/pic1.jpg);
    width: 350px;
    height: 520px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a background image and not an actual inline image element, you need to transition the `background-size` not `transform:scale`.

```css
div.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.wrapper > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background-size 4s ease;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}
div.wrapper:hover > div {
  background-size: 120%;
}
#p1 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="p1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so far. but now the image goes small when i hover it and then it enlarges the content. what could be the problem now?

Comment: The div *has no content*...it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: would you suggest to use the image as an inline image element?

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to do it's hard to comment. If there is more code that we should be aware of, perhaps making a proper ***minimal*** demo in JSfiddle demo.

Comment: http://www.mabehair.com -  i just want to do it like on this page, when i hover an image it should zoom in, when i scroll the pictures should smoothly slide in the scrolling direction.

Comment: My previous comment applies...please don't link the page, create a minimal demo and explain the issue....ideally in a **completely new question**